# Can a verb split a subject and its attributive prepositional phrase?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

Recently a program gave me this text in a dialog box: "All purchases have been downloaded for this account." While I understand its meaning, splitting the subject (the noun and its attributive phrase) makes it awkward in my mind.

"All purchases for this account have been downloaded" seems clearer to me. Is there a grammar rule to cover this?

Comment: "For this account" is a prepositional phrase. An adjective is a word such as *high* or *red*. The sentence does not contain a single adjective.

Comment: @RegDwigh: *all*

Comment: @Cerberus No, he is right. [*All* is a determiner](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PKCzf.png).

Comment: @tchrist: It is both to me. Just depends on your model and definitions.

Comment: @Cerberus I guess it is an aller adjective than it is some.

Comment: @tchrist: It is a possibler adjective than it is impossiblest, don't you think?

Comment: @Cerberus ’Fraid that one gets a flunking grade in English morphology. In English, we form the comparative and superlative degrees of multisyllable adjectives using *more* and *most*. (I’m sure there is a question on this somewhere that you might like to check out.) In any event, “It a more possible adjective that the most impossible one” works perfectly fine, but there are no admissible comparative degree forms for determiners like *all*. Try inflecting *an, the, this, that, these, those, my, thy, both, some, other, all* into comparative and superlative degrees and you will not be happy.

Comment: @tchrist: You don't say. At any rate, this criterion seems rather arbitrary. Most adjectives can have comparatives, others probably can't ("more unique, more ultimate"), and others again certainly can't. To call the last determiners is an excellent idea; but why rip them from the adjectival hands of Mother Tradition entirely?

Comment: @Cerberus Well, if *all* is an adjective, then I guess the original prepositional phrase must have been an adjective, too then, since it was modifying a noun.  Right?

Comment: @tchrist: I would restrict the term "adjective" to single words—as it signifies a part of speech, not a constituent—, but it would be fine to call it adjectival. In fact, attributive and adjectival are often used interchangeably, as in "adjectival clause / adjective clause".

Comment: I bet you are annoyed by the way Obiwan Kenobi speaks.

Comment: I meant Yoda, not obiwan.

Comment: I'd like to bring this back and frame the original context. The program I was referring to is iTunes and I was checking for songs that needed downloading.

@RegDwigh. If "for this account" is a prepositional phrase, it's at the end of the sentence.

Further since by definition a preposition modifies its preceding noun, this sentence asked the reader to do mental gymnastics and jump over the "have been downloaded" and back to the beginning of the sentence to get to the noun.

I guess what we're saying is, "A grammar rule, there is not."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no rule forbidding it, and in general you can move prepositional phrases around quite a bit in a sentence.  (Not everywhere, but quite a bit.)

You just have to realize that they will most often attach themselves to whatever is closest, so people may take the wrong meaning.

This is not a problem if there is something that draws them out to something more distant.  For example, “I washed the baby with that new soap you got” will not attach to *baby* because of the tendency of soap and water to go together.  On the other hand, “I took a picture of the baby with the red cap” has no such issue, since caps do not take pictures.

Answer (score 2):

The English in your dialog box sentence looks grammatical. If you run it by numerous native English speakers, I suspect you will hardly find any reports of a flaw.

The sentence which you propose is not precisely equivalent to the original, but rather subtly different.  The high level semantics are identical, because we know the context, or at least we assume that it's some kind of online shopping situation: from both sentences we understand that this account has associated purchases, and that all of those purchases have been downloaded.

In "all purchases have been downloaded for this account", the phrase "for this account" modifies the verb.

In "all purchases for this account have been downloaded", "purchases for this account" constitutes a noun phrase. That entire phrase is the subject.

The difference is not simply that we are rearranging syntax, because the syntactic categories are changing.

Both of these sentences have multiple possible interpretations, depending on the context and the way words are emphasized in speech. For instance, suppose that an account requires certain purchases to be downloaded, but also requires some other things (let's say *widgets*) to be downloaded. Then "all **purchases** have been downloaded for this account" emphasizes that the purchases have been downloaded, but perhaps the widgets have not yet been.

Also, consider these hypothetical conversations:

> Bob: Alice, for which accounts have all the purchases been downloaded?
>
> Alice: All purchases have been downloaded for *this* account.
>
> Bob: I see.

Versus:

> Bob: Alice, for which accounts have all the purchases been downloaded?
>
> Alice: All purchases for *this* account have been downloaded.
>
> Bob: Yes, yes. I know all purchases were downloaded for *this* account, but were there any other purchases for other accounts?

Comment: Kaz, I think you're right that they are subtly different. No doubt. I guess I was thinking that "all purchases" and "for this account" go together. (It is, indeed, an online store - Apple iTunes.) If we use a more concrete example, such as "This cake was baked for you." That makes sense, more so than, "This cake for you was baked."